# Quick/Nimble notification userInfo testing

Tags: ios, unit-testing, quick-nimble

I was looking at the notifications support in quick/nimble, e.g.:

```
expect {
    NotificationCenter.default.postNotification(testNotification)
}.to(postNotifications(equal([testNotification]))
```

Is there a way to get my hands on the notification that is returned to inspect the userInfo?
My goal is to invoke a method that posts a notification, and then inspect that notification userInfo and make sure that the key/value pairs are correct.

Quick: 2.1.0
Nimble: 8.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
func equalName(_ expectedName: Notification.Name, condition: @escaping (([AnyHashable: Any]) -> Bool)) -> Predicate<[Notification]> {
    return Predicate.define("equal <\(stringify(expectedName))>") { actualExpression, msg in
        guard let actualValue = try actualExpression.evaluate() else {
            return PredicateResult(status: .fail, message: msg)
        }

        let actualNames = actualValue
            .filter { $0.name == expectedName }
            .filter { notification in
                guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {
                    return false
                }

                return condition(userInfo)
            }
            .compactMap { $0.name }
        let matches = actualNames.contains(expectedName)
        return PredicateResult(bool: matches, message: msg)
    }
}
```

and then at the call site you can provide the condition..